# Prometheus: Integrate history data

Tags: python, prometheus, grafana, monitoring, mlops

I want to use grafana and prometheus to monitor some ML models in production. I already have a connector that exports metrics stored in MLFlow and makes them visible to prometheus. I can now query these metrics on prometheus but they are all showed at the current query time.

So far I have managed to provide a different timestamp than just query time by creating a custom Gauge instance.

```py
class MyGauge(Gauge):

    def __init__(self, *args, timestamp=None, **kwargs):

        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self._timestamp = timestamp


    def collect(self):

        metric = self._get_metric()

        for suffix, labels, value, timestamp, exemplar in self._samples():

            metric.add_sample(self._name + suffix, labels, value, timestamp, exemplar)

        return [metric]

 

    def _child_samples(self):

        return (Sample('', {}, self._value.get(), **int((datetime.now() - timedelta(hours=12)).timestamp())**, None),)
```

This works when the time is shifted up to some hours (around 5-6h) with respect to the current time. But as soon as I shift more than 12h, the data points will not appear in prometheus (when I query the metric it results in "empty query result").

Is there any way I can populate a Gauge metric with old values to display data that was generated some months ago? Should I use a different type of metric?

Answer (score 0):

My understanding is that Prometheus disregards metrics with too old timestamps. I believe similar issue was discussed [here](https://github.com/kube-reporting/metering-operator/issues/640).

But you can use [backfilling](https://github.com/prometheus/prometheus/blob/v2.24.0/docs/storage.md#backfilling-from-openmetrics-format) to one time push your historic data to Prometheus. But beware of the `storage.tsdb.retention.time` option, as your data will be deleted shortly if it is out of retention scope.

Or you could try and use some backfilling solutions for Prometheus. For example [this](https://github.com/mtulio/prometheus-backfill) (no affiliation, no guaranties if it works)